# Querying ElasticSearch with C# Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Have an ElasticSearch index where the potential hits are build like this:

```
id: number,
source: string,
type: string,
organization: {
    main: [string],
    support: [string]
},
title: {
    main: [string],
    sub: [string]
}
```

My problem is that I can't search the elements in [].

No problem doing this:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Document>(s => s
                .Index(****)
                .Type(****)
                .MatchAll()
                .Query(q =>
                    q.Term(p => p.source, "some source name")
                ))
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Document>(s => s
                .Index(****)
                .Type(****)
                .MatchAll()
                .Query(q =>
                    q.Term(p => p.organization.main[0], "some organization name")
                ))
```

I have also tried this version, but it also doesn't work:

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Document>(s => s
                .Index(****)
                .Type(****)
                .MatchAll()
                .Query(q =>
                    q.Term(p => p.organization.main, "some organization name")
                ))
```

Can anyone spot what is going wrong?

Comment: May you share index mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `.First()` extension method to reference the `"organization.main"` field in Elasticsearch

```
var searchResults = client.Search<Document>(s => s
    .Index(****)
    .Type(****)
    .MatchAll()
    .Query(q =>
        q.Term(p => p.organization.main.First(), "some organization name")
    )
 );
```

Bear in mind that your query is operating over the whole array here, not the first item in `organization.main` as the usage of `.First()` might imply. Arrays are indexed as multi value fields which are unordered. They come back ordered in the `_source` however.